# How do I get my iPhone app installation date inside the code

Tags: ios

I would like to get the iphone app installation date such that

1. It's the date that the app was first installed
2. Updating the app to a newer version should not change that date
3. Backup and restore an iphone, since the iphone reinstall the app, so the date should be the date the app reinstall

I thought about using UserDefaults to store a date when app is installed, but I know backup will backup that date and the app will not realize it has been reinstalled.

Would I be able to use a cache directory's creation date as the app's install date? If so, can you hint me how?

Comment: As you said, you can use `NSUserDefaults` to get done items (1) and (2). For the last one, you can inspect the URL (or path) of your application sandbox. Maybe the directory name (alpha numeric) will change after a restore.

Comment: Useful thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527231/how-to-detect-an-ios-app-has-been-re-installed-from-xcode-or-upgraded-from-ap

Comment: So you want date when App is first launched or when App is first installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing the following

In NSUserDefaults what ever u put will be available till the application is 
deleted

In application delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method add the following code

```
NSDate *applicationInstalledDate;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL hasLanchedOnce = [defaults boolForKey:@"HasLanchedOnce"];
if(hasLanchedOnce){
    applicationInstalledDate = (NSDate*)[defaults valueForKey:@"applicationInstalledDate"];
} else {
    applicationInstalledDate = [NSDate date];
    [defaults setValue: applicationInstalledDate forKey:@"applicationInstalledDate"];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLanchedOnce"];
}
```

Hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Doesn't [defaults boolForKey:@"HasLanchedOnce"]; get backup and restored? So if I backup my my iphone, then restore it to another phone, on the next time the new device is launched, it'll have the old old date. correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack and could work if this app is the only app for your developer account.  Take a look at the `identifierForVendor` property from UIDevice.  The docs say it will always return the same value as long as one app from the vendor is still installed and if all apps are uninstalled then the value will change.

So if you cached the value the first time the app is run and then compare it each time thereafter then you should be able to detect a change in the value which would mean the app was reinstalled.  Again, very hacky solution.